# Passing value from data table to bean JSF with Confirm Dialog

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm having trouble with passing a single value from the data table to the backing bean. I always get the value of 0 when I try to print it in the method in the confirm dialog but when I try to print it in the method in the command button, it shows the value that I need. I think it resets the value or whatever.

```
<p:dataTable id="labLists" var="lab" value="#{coltsysHome.laboratory}" >
  .....
  <p:column headerText=" ">
        <p:commandButton value="DELETE" onclick="confDlg.show()" icon="ui-icon-closethick" action="#{coltsysHome.action}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lab.lab_id}" target="#{coltsysHome.lab_id_del}" />
         </p:commandButton>
   </p:column>
```

For the confirm dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confDlg" header="DELETE LABORATORY" message="Are you sure you want to delete this lab?">
   <h:form id="delDlgForm">
           <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" oncomplete="confDlg.hide()" actionListener="#{coltsysHome.deleteLab(event)}"/> 
            <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confDlg.hide()" type="button" /> 

    </h:form>
```

Bean (RequestScoped):

```
...getter and setter (lab_id_del)

public void deleteLab(ActionEvent event) {

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String cpath = context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();

    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        ColtsysDAO coltsysDAO = new ColtsysDAO(conn);
        coltsysDAO.deleteLab(lab_id_del, coltsysDAO.getUserID(getUser_name()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
public void action() {
    System.out.println("lab_id_del: " + lab_id_del);
}
```

Comment: What's the bean scope you're using?

Comment: @Andre is `@RequestScoped` as posted in the question.

Comment: Try changing the bean to `@ViewScoped` or wider scope.

Comment: @Luiggi, well that helped :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and foremost change you need to do is: `RequestScoped->ViewScoped` as [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329510/passing-value-from-data-table-to-bean-jsf-with-confirm-dialog/#comment21650360_15329510) has suggested. you might need to add `process` attribute to the `p:commandButton` with the `id` of the `p:dataTable`. Also you can pass the `lab` object directly into `action` method without using `f:setPropertyActionListener` as: `action="#{coltsysHome.action(lab)}"` and take it as: `public String action(Lab lab)`. Why not `actionListener`!